# ActionNext for EditText Does not Work with Fling/Fast Scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-scrollview

I have 3 `EditText` in a vertical sequence (header, main body, footer). The main `EditText` in the middle must handle long text, while the other two just single-line `EditText`.

I want the main `EditText` to have "fling"/fast scrolling. To do so, I wrap it around a `ScrollView`. This is working fine.

However, my problem is when a user hits the "Next" button in soft keyboard in the header `EditText` (single-line, imeOption="actionNext"), the main `EditText` does not receive the next focus (intead, the footer gets the focus).

If I remove the `ScrollView`, then the next-focus is set correctly (but I cannot have the fling/fast scrolling anymore).

Here is my XML layout (there is no code in the activity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:text="Header!" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/main"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/main"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:text="Here we have some really long text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:text="Footer!" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to handle this in run time in the following manner.

```
EditText    firstEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.header);
        final EditText mainEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.main);

        firstEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {

                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                    mainEditText.requestFocus();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```